# Unit of Work / Repository pattern updating multiple sources at the same time

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern, distributed-transactions

I have implemented unit of work / repository pattern for SQL Server and MySql. They work great when I have to update either database server.

A new requirement has come in - for one object type, I need to update **both** SQL Server and MySql at the same time. Ideally, this would be done in a transaction.

Can someone please suggest a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET you can take a look at `TransactionScope` class. It allows you to create distributed transaction over two separate db connections as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). You will need to check what additional configuration is required for MySql to participate in this transaction though.